# PostgreSQL table row goes to the bottom when updating

Tags: postgresql

I am currently migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL in a Laravel application, and I noticed that when updating, the row goes to the end of the table (bottom).

In the application I know I can use ORDER BY to sort, but I am referring to the internal behavior of the database while performing the UPDATE action.

In Mysql, it remains in the same position it occupied before the update.
Is there any way to apply this function? Would it be a InnoDB feature? Using Navicat Premium 12.1 DBMS.

I think this is just an aesthetic factor, but even so I would like to learn how to carry out this "permanent ordination".

The database is in UTF-8 encoding and pt_BR.UTF8 collation and ctype.
Following is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `description` text NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255),
   `rental_price` decimal(10, 2),
   `sale_price` decimal(10, 2)
);
```

Thank you all!

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but generally speaking, you should never expect your DBMS to return your results in a specific way, unless you utilize the `order by` clause.

Comment: @RToyo thanks. You're right. That's why I'm migrating to PostgreSQL to try to get rid of the bad habits MySQL has given me and improve my level of database knowledge.

Comment: @Guilhermao If the answer is correct, please mark the answer as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Part 1: Generally use `ORDER BY`**

If you do not use the `ORDER BY` statement, both MySQL and PostgreSQL (and for that matter most relational DBMS systems) do not make any promises about the order of records.

You should refactor your application to use the `ORDER BY` statement. If you want your data set to be ordered by newest first, you could use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY id DESC;
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY creation_date DESC; -- if your table has such a column
```

Similarly, you can have oldest objects first by using one of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY id ASC;
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY creation_date ASC; -- if your table has such a column
```

**Part 2: Looking into the mechanics**

You added to your question a more detailed inquiry:

> [...] I know I can use ORDER BY to sort, but I am referring to the internal behavior of the database while performing the UPDATE action.

There is multiple things that influence the sequence of database records displayed on your screen, when performing a query. In a real life application, it is not (practially) possible to predict this sequence.

I assume this is simply an effect of PostgreSQL creating a new record for the updated record as can be found [here](https://facility9.com/2011/04/postgresql-update-internals/) in the *Updating a Row* section. I suggest to not rely on this behvaiour in any of your applications.

Comment: Nice! Do you think this has any negative impact on retrieving data?

Comment: I don‘t know. But I suggest to open another question. Surely somebody here will have an answer :-) if you like the answer to this question please consider upvoting and marking it as the right answer

Comment: @Guilhermao The `order by` clause will impact how quickly your database can retrieve the data. Think of it like any other list of data - if you want an ordered list of data, you have to go through every row to evaluate what order to place it in. If you would like to speed that up, you can build an `index` on the row you want to order by - it basically creates an ordered list of values for that column, with a reference to the original row. That way the DB can simply lookup the order from the already-ordered list, instead of doing a table scan. Indexing is a very important concept to learn.